# WPF Combobox SelectionChanged event

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a project where I have a ComboBox interacting with 2 Sliders.
Each o these 3 controls are triggered by events: namely a SelectionChanged for the ComboBox and a ValueChanged for the 2 sliders.

I thought the ValueChanged event was giving me problems, not updating the values and min/max accordingly to the combobox selection. For some reason I assumed that maybe both events were triggered simultaneously resulting in a mix up of my variables.

Well, I decided to change my ValueChanged events so that they only update a label so see if that fixed the problem. It did not.

In other words, the SelectionChanged event is where my problem is lying.

Looking through my code I didn't see any problem, and at this point the only thing I can think of is as follow:

```
private void chanList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
switch (chanList.Text)
 {
                case "Channel 1":
                    { // blablabla }

 }
}
```

Reason for the problem is that chanList.Text doesn't contain the "new selection", it still contains the old one. I am guessing that when the "SelectionChanged" event is triggered, the content of the of combobox (in my case chanList.Text) is not yet "updated". So it results in picking up the wrong case in my switch.

Now my questions:
1. are my assumptions correct?
2. if so, what should I replace my Switch test by? Assuming chanList.Text isn't updated yet, maybe going with something chanList.SelectedItem should be the way to go. However, I was able to find the correct verbose to access the content (text) of the selected item... That's why I was going with chanList.Text which has been working fine well at least until I started using that event.

Thanks for the help!
Steve

Comment: Set breakpoints and test your assumptions.

Comment: [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in code and post it here in your question. In that way, we can test your problem and find a solution. As it is, any number of things could be causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The combobox text will not be changed in the SelectionChanged event handler.  The selections will be found in the SelectionChangedEventArgs object.  Specifically e.AddedItems.  It is possible, although perhaps not for your control, that the user will have selected multiple items in the combobox, so e.AddedItems is a list.  Scroll through the list and make the updates necessary.

```
    private void chanList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (object item in e.AddedItems)
        {
            if (item is string)
            {
                switch (item as string)
                {
                    case "Channel 1":
                        Console.WriteLine("Channel 1");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```